# Is it possibly to get Frame.Content from Uri?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to load XAML file from Inkscape https://inkscape.org/  to Frame.

```
frame1.Source = new Uri("Name.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

It works fine.
But how I can get `frame1.Content` after it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This file is NOT compatible with Silverlight-->
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
  <Canvas Name="svg2" Width="744.09448819" Height="1052.3622047">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Canvas.Resources/>
    <Canvas Name="layer1">
      <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="137.14285" Canvas.Top="169.50507" Width="182.85715" Height="320" Name="rect3336" Fill="#FF0000FF" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat"/>
    </Canvas>
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `ContentRendered` event of `Frame`. It gives a chance to get rendered `UserControl` and take all controls through casting. For example:

```
private void frame1_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var yourXAML = frame1.Content as Page; // It is now Name.xaml
}
```

Comment: You mean  frame1.content As Viewbox. But how I can get/set property Rectangle in my Examlpe?

Comment: Ok I found (frame1.Content as ViewBox).FindChild("rect3336").